# Conditionally Enable Custom Converter based on a Users Input

Tags: xpages

I would like to conditionally run a custom converter. I have an XPages that handles editing and new data on the same page. The user selected a radio button to edit or create a new item.

The input fields are shared between these two functions. Upon page load I do not know what the user will do so I cannot use the "Loaded" property of the converter.

I need to format the data in this format '$900,000'.  *Note that there is no cents in my required format.*

The built in converter for numbers or currency fails me because no matter what I do, it **always** add the cents. I assume that this is a bug in XPages. It doesn't matter if I say "Integer Only" or set the Maximum Fraction Digits to zero. The cents do not go away.

I have a custom converter that works fine for me, but only works when it is recalculated once, and fails when recalculated. I have tried setting the partial refresh updates to "Do not validate or update data" and this works, but breaks other parts of the page where I needs the updates to be enabled.

This application is soon to be deployed and it is too late for me to re-engineer the whole page structure to solve this issue -- too many moving parts. All I need to do to please the testers it to get rid of the cents (xxxx.00) that are added to the value, and still have everything else work.

My problem is singular, but my questions are tri-fold. How can I:

- Get the built-in currency converter to remove cents the way it should? Or
- Get the custom converter to be enabled ONLY based on a user-entered value? Or
- Help me think of a different approach to solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get any of the answers above to work, so I cloned the text box. I made one show up for "Edit", and one show up for "New".  I kept everything the same, but only added the custom converter to the one that shows for "Edit".

Thanks again for all your help. The XPages community rocks!

Answer (score 1):

Steve, I have really fought a battle with converters as another problem is that they are all run prior to validation - and as such error messages are not necessarily shown in sequential order.

Therefore, I ended up using validators (also for the work of the converters). And on top of that I use "binding" of the components (not the values) to easily access other fields on the same page. This allows for conditional checks/logic. If you have not tried component binding, then there is a [great introduction by Tim Tripcony](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPid1_HfvFM).

/John

Comment: Thanks John, good suggestion. I will try that on Monday.  Meanwhile, I am still open to any and all suggestions or fixes

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I need to understand component binding, and anything by Tim Tripcony is useful reading.

Answer (score 1):

A couple ways to do this, One would be to do the conditionally checking of user in the custom converter.  Another approach would be to use a PhaseListener and in RenderResponse Phase get the Component and set the Converter on the component to null when you don't need it on the component.  I typically don't use converter though if its just the display of the number, just if I actually need the value converted.  I would use something like a display Mask I've recently used a jquery plugin called [maskMoney](https://plugins.jquery.com/maskMoney/) that worked well for a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help Toby. I tried to put conditional checks in my custom converter, and at first this seemed to work, but broke other things. I definitely need to know and understand more about the PhaseListners. I will also check out that jQuery plugin. See my answer for what I actually got to work.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your converter is on an editable field, because otherwise it won't fail on submitting data.

The problem sounds to be timing. The converter has to run during page load, in order to convert the Number value stored in the database to a String value required by the browser. So some default needs to be set, which presumably is to connect it.

If you're then wanting to change the display option based on input, you've got to do a partial refresh *after* the input, in order to recalculated whether cents should appear.

Once the inputted value is passed back from the browser to the underlying component tree, you can calculate accordingly - providing your converter knows what to interact with. The process dugint he partial refresh is to restore the component tree, apply the request values (store the String value from the browser into the submittedValue property of each component), process any converters or validators, then update the component tree. So when the converter runs, the radio button's value property isn't set, so it works on the last refresh's setting - the default.

By choosing "Do not validate or update data" then you're saying don't bother writing back any inputted entries from the browser into the component tree. So I'm sure you can that means the converter will know nothing about what's been input.

John's suggestion on binding is a good one, but remember you'll be needing the submittedValue property of the relevant component. For a radio button, I'm not 100% sure what that will be, but you should be able to print it out.

The mask approach may work. Someone else used that recently to make integers work right.

The other option is to look at the Extension Library's Dojo Number Validation Text Box, which has a javaType property and a more flexible set of converters. That may well allow you to avoid cents. If it does and you don't want the Dojo look and feel, it's converter should give some ideas on what your converter needs to do to remove cents.

Comment: Thanks Paul for your answer. I tried the dojo text box, and it wouldn't display any converter.  It also didn't apply my styles at all. Frustrated, I then thought of another way, that I should have thought of before. See my answer for what eventually worked.